Why does rsync not set file permissions correctly when transferring from local to remote?
I am trying to copy a file from server A (Raspberry Pi) to server B (NAS). On server A the file has -rw-rw-r--. I want the file to have permissions -rw-r--r-- after the transfer.
umask is 0022 on each server. If I create a file on Server B… touch test file it gets these file permissions:
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Oct 20 16:21 testfile

When I run this rsync command from server B (remote to local):
rsync -itrvv --info=progress2 --include="*mymovie*" --exclude="*" "/media/ubuntu/movie/mymovie.mp4" /media/hdd/movies

After the transfer the file permissions are: -rwxr-xr-x
Already I don't know why all the execution bits are set?
Instead if I run this from server B (remote to local):
rsync -itrvvp --info=progress2 --include="*mymovie*" --exclude="*" --chmod=F644 "/media/ubuntu/movie/mymovie.mp4" /media/hdd/movies

Now after the transfer the file permissions are: -rw-r--r-- as expected. But I don't understand why I had to specifically set the permissions just to get the default file permissions of -rw-r--r-- for that Server?
But if I run these commands from Server A the file permissions are never -rw-r--r-- after the transfer.
When I run these commands from server A (local to remote):
rsync -itrvv --info=progress2 --include="*mymovie*" --exclude="*" "/media/ubuntu/movie/mymovie.mp4" /media/hdd/movies
sudo rsync -itrvvp --info=progress2 --include="*mymovie*" --exclude="*" --chmod=Du=rwx,Dg=rx,Do=rx,Fu=rw,Fg=r,Fo=r "/media/ubuntu/movie/mymovie.mp4" /media/hdd/movies
sudo rsync -itrvvp --info=progress2 --include="*mymovie*" --exclude="*" --chmod=F644 "/media/ubuntu/movie/mymovie.mp4" /media/hdd/movies

In each case after the transfer to Server B (NAS) the file permissions are always: -rwxr--r--.
My question:  How do I give mymovie.mp4 file permission of -rw-r--r-- after using rsync to transfer it from Server A to Server B when I run the rsync command from Server A? (i.e: local to remote). Why are execution bits being added in?
Some more information: The source and destination folders (on Server A and B) are exposed as Samba shares. On Server B (NAS) this is how the share is defined:
[Harddisk]
        comment = The harddisk
        path = /media/hdd
        guest ok = Yes
        read only = No
        valid users = root kids
        admin users = root
        force create mode = 0600
        force directory mode = 0700
        wide links = yes
        follow symlinks = yes

And then I mount that from Server A (Pi) using -cifs in systemd like this:
[Unit]
Description=Mount Internal HDD on Server B (NAS) to Server A (Raspberry Pi):
[Mount]
What=//192.168.1.104/Harddisk
Where=/media/hdd/movies
Type=cifs
Options=x-mount.mkdir,noperm,_netdev,nofail,uid=1000,gid=1000,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644,credentials=/etc/login.cred

TimeoutSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Update: Regarding my first test above: Running the rsync command from Server B (Remote to Local). Why are all the execution bits being set after the file transfer?
I made a change to the -cifs options that were auto-mounting the samba share the file was being copied from (Server A) with different file_mode 0644 and dir_mode 0755 and now the execution bits are not getting set. But I still don't fully understand this.
Regarding the rest of my query:  Running the rsync command from Server A (Local to Remote). I also updated the -cifs options to clarify use of file_mode and dir_mode same as above. I also played around with the Samba share definitions on Server B (smb.conf) and by combining force create mode with create mask I was able to force files to have a specific permission when rsync copies them in to that Samba Share. However I am still unable to have rsync give files whatever permission it wants after it transfers them to a remote Samba share. I have set unix extensions = Yes but they do not seem to be obeyed.
